# Eager loading in many to many in laravel eloquent relationship (Retrieve all Posts with their assigned tags)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

My blog laravel project has many Posts and each Post belongs to many tags. 
Now I want to retrieve all blogs and their tags and echo each tag.

Here is the code I have written. Is there any better way?

```
$posts = Post::with('tags')->get();

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        foreach ($post->tags as $tag) {
            echo "<pre> $tag->name </pre>";
        }
    }
    die();
```

Comment: You can take a look here. I am also using these on my blog https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-taggable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all tags with `Eager loading` as you do in your code.

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

```php
$posts = App\Post::with('tags:name')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    foreach ($post->tags as $tag) {
        echo "<pre> $tag->name </pre>";
    }
}
```

It is the correct solution.

You can even do it with `DB` queries to get it faster but probably your way is just enough.

```php
$posts = App\Post::all()->pluck('id');

return DB::select('SELECT name FROM tags WHERE id in (' . implode(',', $posts) . ')');
```

**Final tip:** Do not merge HTML view with the logic.

Comment: Is there any solution without using double foreach? I am actually asking for my learning purpose.

Comment: If you want to take the tags inside the posts, there is no other solution. You can use an `array_map` for example, but in the end, still being a loop.